# Django deployment issues w/Plesk "No WSGI daemon process called '<>' has been configured"

Tags: apache, mod-wsgi, wsgi, plesk

I've been successful in deploying various Django sites with apache before, but I'm on a server which has a Plesk distribution installed. So, in getting setup I have deployed a pretty basic application:

[Basic contents of the Django Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzvST.png)

The permissions that have been blacked out all contain the ***same*** username.

However, the apache `error_logs` for this domain is showing the following error:

```
2018-09-30 13:55:06 [wsgi:error] No WSGI daemon process called 'daemonuplordvexxos' has been configured: /var/www/vhosts/winduplordvexxos.com/api.winduplordvexxos.com/apiuplordvexxos/wsgi.py
```

My additional apache directives are as follows (where I have setup https):

[Additional Apache Directives](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0onUI.png)

Googling the vital line `No WSGI daemon process called 'daemonuplordvexxos' has been configured` has yielded zero luck.

My `wsgi.py` file is a standard from Django 2.1.1 install:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'apiuplordvexxos.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

I'm not sure if this will help anyone diagnose my issues:

[Name duplicates previous WSGI daemon definition.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeVct.png)

Comment: Is `mod_wgci` installed and enabled on the server? It is not shipped with Plesk by default.

Comment: @ElvisPlesky Sorry if this sounds ignorant, but I'm not sure what `mod_wgci` is...

Comment: `mod_wsgi` is an Apache module which provides an interface for hosting Python applications. Please check if it is installed using `# apachectl -M | grep wcgi`.

Comment: @ElvisPlesky Oh, you wrote something different. mod_wsgi is installed nonetheless.

Comment: Oh sorry. That is some heavy typo I have made.

Comment: @WindUpLordVexxos, did you figure out what the issue was here? I'm having a similar issue currently!